# reading a file to string in JavaScript. Reading only last line

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to read a poem from a file: "dererlkoenig"

```
var contents = fs.readFileSync(("dererlkoenig"), 'utf8');
console.log(contents);
```

but nodejs prints me only

```
In seinen Armen das Kind war tot.te Kind,ch an!t
```

The whole poem is much longer

```
Der Erlkoenig
    Wer reitet so spaet durch Nacht und Wind?
    Es ist der Vater mit seinem Kind
    Er hat den Knaben wohl in dem Arm,
    Er fasst ihn sicher, er haelt ihn warm.
    (...)
    In seinen Armen das Kind war tot.
```

I really don't get why it reads only last line. Is there any way to read the whole file to string variable

Comment: @C.Lightfoot I think your link deals with the front-end fileReader only

Comment: Ah, let me delete it then.

Comment: [The NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) does indication that it "Returns the contents of the `path`." What happens if you async `readFile`, and use a callback similar to their [example](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)?

Comment: This is really strange, I just ran you code in my node and it printed the whole file.

Comment: I tried in linux and windows. I have the same results

Comment: Because of the `te Kind,ch an!t`  after the, `In seinen Armen das Kind war tot.`  I would assume, that it not only reads the end of the file, but that the file contains something that would cause the terminal to print it that way. e.g. some chars that would reset the cursor position.